# How do I save the Custom Spinner state

Tags: java, android

I extended android.widget.Spinner. and added an int field to my implementation. Now I want it to save the field value on orientation change. My first thought was using Bundle object for that:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable(SUPER_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState())
    bundle.putInt(PREV_ITEM, this.prevItem) // ... save stuff
    return bundle
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
    val newState: Parcelable
    if (state is Bundle) {
        this.prevItem = state.getInt(PREV_ITEM) // ... load stuff
        newState = state.getParcelable<Parcelable>(SUPER_STATE)
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(newState)
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner$SavedState
```

So I found Spinner [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java) and figured out that I have to extend inner static class SavedState and use it to save my field value. But I wasn't able to do that. Android Studio suggests that it "Cannot resolve symbol 'Saved State'".
[image]

So what do I do to save the state of my custom Spinner?

Comment: the better way is to use a static value and assign the selected position to that static value and set that value in onResume method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually extend Spinner.SavedState because it created inside Spinner class. Even if you try to override Spinner.onSaveInstanceState you cannot implement this method in your custom class, because you don't have access to private variables of Spinner class.

What you can actually do is to create new class implementing Parcelable and use value returned from base class to construct your own class.

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    final MySavedState ss = new MySavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
    ss.myInt = 100;
    return ss;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    MySavedState ss = (MySavedState) state;

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

    if(ss.myInt == 100) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Success!");
    }
}

static class MySavedState extends Spinner.BaseSavedState {

    int myInt;

    public MySavedState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    public MySavedState(Parcel source) {
        super(source);

        myInt = source.readInt();
    }
}
```